# What are the adjusted odds of winning if a known variable is set, given winrate with and without variable?

Tags: probability

Lets say a sailor plays 300 games of arm wrestling with 70% winrate.
In 200 of those matches, a can of spinach is consumed prior, the subset of these games gave 80% winrate.

If the sailor stops eating spinach forever, what is his expected winrate?

Comment: The question's choice of variables would need to be improved, and the answer adjusted. This problem enters brain-fart territory. It's too easy to work out because 80%-70% represents the difference of 1/3 of matches without spinach. .'. 3/3 of matches is simply 80% - (10%*3) = 50%

Comment: I should clarify that Remy was kind enough to give me the method of the solution to this type of problem, instead of the simple but misleading hack-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he won $80$% of the $200$ matches with spinach then he won $160$ matches with spinach. You must find how many more won matches of the remaining $100$ result in a $70$% total win-rate. We have

$$\frac{160+x}{200+100}=0.7$$

The resulting win-rate without spinach is $\frac{x}{100}$

Comment: x = 50 matches won without spinach ∴ 50% winrate without spinach. Thanks Remy